# Android KSoap get the java.io.FileNotFoundException on HttpTransportSE and throw the XmlPullParserException

Tags: android, ssl, https, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to make Https connections on the Android phones to Wcf service. I read a lot of tutorials about Https on Android via KSoap. Now I can pass the certificate checking. But I can not make the connection to https web service. I always faced the XmlParserExceptoin.

```
10-19 17:24:34.840: ERROR/HttpsTest(16518): XmlPullParserException
10-19 17:24:34.840: ERROR/HttpsTest(16518): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44de6a40) 
10-19 17:24:34.840: ERROR/HttpsTest(16518):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
```

I debug the app and see when the HttpsURLConnectionImpl object in the ServiceConnection try to connect to the service : https://192.168.100.66:443/Service1.svc/basic. It throws an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://192.168.100.66:443/Service1.svc/basic
```

I spent many times for this issue but I'm still stuck with it. How can I connect to the web service via Android KSoap ?, anyone can help me, I really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF is rest ful then use simple Http request to make connection in following way

`URL url = new URL("your url with parameter");`

URLConnection yc = url .openConnection();

this is what i have done in my code when i am working with WCF and i am getting resopnse from server.